# Writing to a DOT file that is read by GraphViz

Tags: graphviz, filewriter, dot

I'm creating a program that writes to a dot file. The file writes will include lines with < and >

for example :

```
List<Integer>
```

However, when I'm reading in the file with GraphViz it treats these < as part of the dot file syntax instead of just as text.

How can I escape these characters or make it so that the < or > are just part of the label instead of part of the syntax?

edit: clarification:

```
digraph G {
GameState [  shape=Mrecord, label= "{<f0>GameState |<f1>|<f2> getRemainingLines :List<Line> \n toString : String \n }"] 
}
```

This would be my graph but it doesn't display the seperate sections because of the `<Line>`. How could I get it to print out the part between  and \n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--edit--  changed to answer based on clarification

just use backslashes  to escape the `<` and `>`

```
digraph G {
  GameState [  shape=Mrecord, label= "{<f0>GameState |<f1>|<f2> getRemainingLines :List\<Line\> \n toString : String \n}"]
}
```

[image: dot -Tpng game.dot -o foo.png]

Comment: It didn't work for me sorry. I added clarification in my question so you can see my example. thanks